# Symmetrical PDF. How to find its double integral.

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, definite-integrals

The probability density function of a random variable X is symmetric about 0. Then

$$\int_{-2}^2 \int_{-\infty}^x f(u) du dx$$    is?

I figured that integral of a PDF from $-\infty$ to $x$ would be it's cdf. But how should I integrate next?

Comment: Should it be $f(u,x)$?

Comment: No it's just $f(u)$ in the question.

Comment: A vocabulary issue: You should say that the pdf is an **even** **function**, and keep "symmetric" (with respect to $y$ axis) for qualifying its **curve**.

Comment: Another little grammatical remark: in your title, you should write "its" instead of "it's", which is an abbreviation "it is".

Answer (score 3):

**Hints:**

- Let $F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(u) du$.
  Then, we have 
  \begin{align*} 
  F(x) &= \int_{-\infty}^x f(u) du \\
  &= \int_{-\infty}^x f(-u)(-1)(-1) du \\
  &= - \int_{\infty}^{-x} f(u) du \\
  &= \int_{-x}^{\infty} f(u) du \\
  &= 1 - F(-x).
  \end{align*}
  That is, the function
  $$ G(x) = F(x) - \frac12 $$
  is odd around $0$.
- Now, what is 
  $$ \int_{-2}^2 F(x) dx = \int_{-2}^2 \frac12 + G(x) dx? $$

Comment: [+1] fine hint.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\int_{-2}^{2}\int_{-\infty}^{x}\mrm{f}\pars{u}\,\dd u\,\dd x & =
\int_{-2}^{2}\int_{-\infty}^{2}\bracks{u < x}\mrm{f}\pars{u}\,\dd u\,\dd x =
\int_{-\infty}^{2}\mrm{f}\pars{u}\int_{-2}^{2}\bracks{x > u}\,\dd x\,\dd u
\\[5mm] & =
\int_{-\infty}^{2}\mrm{f}\pars{u}
\braces{\bracks{u < 0}\int_{-2}^{2}\,\dd x +
\bracks{0 < u < 2}\int_{u}^{2}\,\dd x}\,\dd u
\\[5mm] & =
4\int_{-\infty}^{0}\mrm{f}\pars{u} + \int_{0}^{2}\mrm{f}\pars{u}\pars{2 - u}\,\dd u
\end{align}